# Bazaar: How to restart central repository from checkout

Tags: bazaar

I set up an central repository on a remote server. I develop locally on my laptop using a checkout of the central repository.

Last week the remote server died. I understand that I can unbind the local checkout and work locally, but how can I use my local checkouts to recreate the central repo?

This is the setup i used: [Centralized Workflow](http://doc.bazaar.canonical.com/beta/en/tutorials/centralized_workflow.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `bzr unbind` your branch, then `bzr push` the content to the remote server again and then `bzr bind` again.